# Prove the uniformity of the Cantor/Lebesgue function defined on $A^c$ where $A$ is a Cantor set on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

I am reading *Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space* by Frank Jones. My question is specifically regarding Chapter 4, Section C titled "The Lebesgue Function Associated with a Cantor Set". The author denotes the function as $f$ and defines it on the union of the open intervals $J_r$ of a Cantor set in $[0,1]$.

On page 87, the author picks two points $x,y \in A^c$ and $|x-y| \leq \mathcal{l}_3$ where $\mathcal{l}_3$ is the length of the closed intervals of the Cantor set. Of course, if neither $x$ nor $y$ belongs to one of these closed intervals, then $x$ and $y$ must belong to the same excluded open interval so $f(x)=f(y)$. This makes sense to me.

However, the author then goes on to state,

> We therefore assume that either $x$ or $y$ (or both) belongs to one of these closed intervals.

This above statement confuses me If we're trying to prove something for a function defined on $A^c$, which are the open intervals removed from the Cantor set, then why/how can we assume that $x$ or $y$ belongs to one of the closed intervals?

It would help if someone that has the book could opine, although I hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind the difference between the Cantor set $A$ (which does not contain any intervals), and "pre-Cantor" sets, which consist of $2^k$ disjoint closed intervals of equal length $l_k$. It seems the author does not introduce any notation for pre-Cantor sets; I'll call them $A_k$. So,
$$A = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty A_k$$ 
The function $f$ is defined on the complement of $A$. The author estimates $|f(x)-f(y)|$ from above, as follows:

1. Pick $x,y\in A^c$
2. Suppose there is $k$ such that $|x-y|\le l_k$
3. Then either

   - $x,y\in A_k^c$,  in which case $f(x)=f(y)$, or
   - $x\in A_k$, $y\in A_k^c$, or
   - $x\in A_k^c$, $y\in A_k$ (which is essentially the same as preceding),  or
   - $x\in A_k$, $y\in A_k$

The author then proceeds to estimate $|f(x)-f(y)|$ considering each case separately.

Comment: Thank you for a lucid explanation. Is this a stylistic choice on the author's part that is reasonable to expect most readers to understand or would most writers make the distinction between $A$ and $A_k$?

Comment: In my experience, most arguments involving Cantor sets  introduce some notation for pre-Cantor sets. But I find the author's exposition reasonable; he just prefers to talk about "black intervals" instead of attaching any name to their union.